# Round Robin Scheduling With Arrival Time (concept of wait queue)

Tags: c, scheduling, scheduler, rounding

i was studying round robin and there was a concept of wait queue which struck my mind so i searched the internet and found nothing over it. So 
How a round robin scheduling algorithm will be solved if there is an arrival time for the given process?

Answer (score 0):

Round Robin Scheduling is the technique which executes a process for the given time slice and then appends that process at the end of the ready queue, before appending it at the end of the ready queue, it checks whether there are any other process which can be inserted in the queue(on the basis of arrival time) if such process exists then it inserts such programs in the queue and then at the end of the queue it adds the current executed process